# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type CartItem is not part of the model for the current context.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I just started with asp.net mvc . I want to add cart for services. I got database for this project writen in sql scripts like:

```
Create table [Laundries].[CartItems](
[Id]                        BIGINT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CartId]                    BIGINT                      NOT NULL,
[Price]                     FLOAT                       NOT NULL,
[ServiceId]                 BIGINT                      NOT NULL,
[UserId]                    BIGINT                      NULL,
[Quantity]                  BIGINT                      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Laundries.Carts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Laundries.Services] FOREIGN KEY([ServiceId])
    REFERENCES [Laundries].[Services]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Laundries.Carts1] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
    REFERENCES [Core].[Users]([Id]),
```

);

I got service for cart

```
    using Ideo.Mvc.Data.Model;
using Ideo.Mvc.Data.Model.Core;
using Ideo.Mvc.Data.Model.Laundries;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace Ideo.Mvc.Data.Services.Core
{
    public partial class ShoppingCart
    {
        long? ShoppingCartId { get; set; }

        public const string CartSessionKey = "CartId";


        #region GetCart()
        public static List<CartItem> GetCart(long? userId)
        {
            List<CartItem> listOfItemsInCart;
            using (var context = Context.Read())
            {
                listOfItemsInCart = context.Query<CartItem>().
                Where
                (
                p => p.UserId == userId).
                ToList()
                ;
            }

            return listOfItemsInCart;

        }

        #endregion


        #region GetList()

        public static IEnumerable<TResult> GetList<TResult>(IPager pager, long? cartId = null, int? quantity = null,  long? serviceId = null)
        {
            using (var context = Context.Read())
            {
                var query = context.Query<CartItem>().AsQueryable();

                if (cartId != null)
                {
                    query = query.Where(p => p.CartId.Equals(cartId));
                }
                if (quantity != null)
                {
                    query = query.Where(p => p.Quantity.Equals(quantity));
                }
                if (quantity != null)
                {
                    query = query.Where(p => p.Quantity.Equals(quantity));
                }

                if (serviceId != null)
                {
                    query = query.Where(p => p.ServiceId.Equals(serviceId));
                }
                //query = query.Where(p => p.IsActive == true && p.IsVerified == true);
                return query
                    .Pager(pager)
                    .GetResult<TResult>();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        //public static ShoppingCart GetCart()
        //{
        //    // redirect
        //}

        #region AddToCart()
        public void AddToCart(Service service)//
        {
            CartItem cartItem;
            using (var context = Context.Read())
            {
                cartItem = context.Query<CartItem>().
                SingleOrDefault(
                p => p.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                && p.ServiceId == service.Id);//
            }
            if (cartItem == null)
            {
                cartItem = new CartItem
                {
                    ServiceId = service.Id,
                    CartId = ShoppingCartId,
                    Quantity = 1,
                };
                using (var context = Context.Write())
                {
                    context.Create(cartItem);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }


        #endregion

        public int RemoveFromCart(long id)
        {
            CartItem cartItem;
            using (var context = Context.Read())
            {
                cartItem = context.Query<CartItem>().
                Single(
                p => p.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                && p.ServiceId == id);
            }
            int itemCount = 0;

            if (cartItem != null)
            {
                if (cartItem.Quantity > 1)
                {
                    cartItem.Quantity--;
                    itemCount = cartItem.Quantity;
                    using (var context = Context.Write())
                    {
                        context.Update(cartItem);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var context = Context.Write())
                    {
                        context.Delete(cartItem);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            return itemCount;
        }

        public void EmptyCart()
        {
            List<CartItem> cartItems;
            using (var context = Context.Read())
            {
                cartItems = context.Query<CartItem>().
                Where(
                p => p.CartId == ShoppingCartId).
                ToList();
            }
            foreach (var cartItem in cartItems)
            {
                using (var context = Context.Write())
                {
                    context.Delete(cartItem);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }


        public List<CartItem> GetCartItems()
        {
            List<CartItem> cartItems;
            using (var context = Context.Read())
            {
                cartItems = context.Query<CartItem>().
                Where(
                p => p.Id == ShoppingCartId).
                ToList();
            }
            return cartItems;
        }

        public int GetCount()
        {
            int? count;

            using (var context = Context.Read())
            {
                count = context.Query<CartItem>().
                Where(
                p => p.Id == ShoppingCartId).
                Select(p => p.Quantity).
                Sum();
            }
            return count ?? 0;
        }

        public double GetTotal()
        {
            float? total;
            using (var context = Context.Read())
            {
                total = context.Query<CartItem>().
                    Where(
                    p => p.Id == ShoppingCartId).
                    Select(p => p.Quantity * p.Service.ServicePrice).Cast<float?>()
                    .Sum();
            }
            return total ?? 0;

        }



        public long CreateOrder(Orders order)
        {
            double? orderTotal = 0;
            var cartItems = GetCartItems();
            foreach (var item in cartItems)
            {
                var orderDetail = new OrdersDetalis
                {
                    ServiceId = item.ServiceId,
                    OrderId = order.Id,
                    NetPrice = item.Service.ServicePrice,
                    GrossPrice = (item.Service.ServicePrice * 1.23),
                    Quantity = item.Quantity
                };
                orderTotal += item.Quantity * item.Service.ServicePrice;

                using (var context = Context.Write())
                {
                    context.Create(orderDetail);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            order.SumNetPrice = orderTotal;
            order.OrderDateUtc = DateTime.Now;
            order.StatusId = 1;
            //TODO wyliczanie kolejnego zamówienia
            order.OrderNumber = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year) + "/" + order.Laundry + "/" + 1;

            using (var context = Context.Write())
            {
                context.Create(order);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            EmptyCart();
            return order.Id;
        }

        public long? GetCartId(long? userId)
        {

            long? cartId;
            using (var context = Context.Read())
            {
                var query = context.Query<CartItem>().AsQueryable();

                query = query.Where(p => p.UserId == userId);
                cartId = query.FirstOrDefault().Id;

            }

            return cartId;
        }
        // When a user has logged in, migrate their shopping cart to
        // be associated with their username
        //public void MigrateCart(long userId)
        //{
        //    List<CartItem> shoppingCart;
        //    //ShoppingCartService shoppingCart;
        //    using (var context = Context.Read())
        //    {
        //        var query = context.Query<CartItem>().AsQueryable();

        //        query = query.Where(p => p.UserId == UserId);
        //        query = query.Where(p => p.CityId == CityId);

        //        return query.FirstOrDefault();
        //    }
        //    foreach (Cart item in shoppingCart)
        //    {
        //        item.CartId = userName;
        //    }
        //    storeDB.SaveChanges();
        //}
    }
}
```

and controller

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Ideo.Mvc.Data.Model.Core;
using Ideo.Mvc.Data.Services.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Ideo.Mvc.Data.Model.Laundries;
using Ideo.Mvc.Web.Areas.Default.Models.Carts;

namespace Ideo.Mvc.Web.Areas.Default.Controllers
{
    public partial class ShoppingCartController : Controller
    {

        public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {
            var userID = Convert.ToInt64(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
            {
                CartItems = ShoppingCart.GetCart(userID),

            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        //[HttpPost]
        //[ActionName("List")]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        //#region List()
        //public virtual ActionResult List(ShoppingCartDataSource dataSource)
        //{
        //    dataSource.Data = ShoppingCart.GetList<CartListViewModel>(
        //        dataSource,
        //        dataSource.CartId,
        //        dataSource.Quantity,
        //        dataSource.DateCreated,
        //        dataSource.UserId

        //        );
        //    return View(MVC.Default.ShoppingCart.Views.ViewNames.List, dataSource);


        //}

        //#endregion
        public virtual ActionResult AddToCart(Service service)
        {
            var userID = Convert.ToInt64(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(userID);
            ShoppingCart.AddToCart(service);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult RemoveFromCart(long id)
        {
            var userID = Convert.ToInt64(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(userID);


            string serviceName = "andrzej";//TODO getServiceNameById(id)

            // Remove from cart
            int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

            // Display the confirmation message
            var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = Server.HtmlEncode(serviceName) +
                    "[[[ zotał usunięty z twojego koszyka]]]",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = itemCount,
                DeleteId = id
            };
            return Json(results);
        }
        //
       // [HttpPost]
        // GET: /ShoppingCart/CartSummary
        //[ChildActionOnly]
        public virtual ActionResult CartSummary()
        {
            long? userID = Convert.ToInt64(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(userID);

            ViewData["CartCount"] = cart.GetCount();
            return PartialView("CartSummary");
        }

        //[HttpPost]
        //public virtual ActionResult CreateOrder()
        //{
        //    var userID = Convert.ToInt64(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        //    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(userID);


        //}
    }
}
```

i know it's messed up
I want to rewrite it again but i cannot understand when i go to shoopingcart/index i got error like in title "The entity type CartItem is not part of the model for the current context"

And here is the view to shop all items in cart. It's basic. I have to work on this view but first i need to sort controller/service.
    @using Ideo.Mvc.Web.Areas.Default.Models
    @model CmpnyMessageDataSource

```
@foreach (var message in Model.Data)
{
    using (var p = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Panel()))
    {

        @p.Heading(@message.Date.ToString("g"));

        using (p.BeginBody())
        {
            <p>@message.Content</p>
        }

        // @p.Footer()
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the view as well, it may be that your are referring to something else in the view

Comment: I added view but i think the problem is in service/controller for sure.